# Javascript in html syntax in link

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem adding a js variable inside a html link where I believe I have the syntax wrong as it's not adding the content of the variable to the link string.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url+'">
```

Where I'm I going wrong here?

Comment: When should that js (the string concatenation) be executed? What is the `url` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible to do :).
You have to do it javascript all the way, like:

```
href="javascript: document.location='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + url;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to treat HTML as if it were JavaScript. You can't just jump in and out of the two languages.

If you want to modify an existing link, you need to use DOM Manipulation. This is covered as part of the [introduction to JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) hosted by the W3C.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You will need to use javascript like this:

... within `<head>` tag ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myLink').href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+url;
}
</script>
```

... within `<body>` tag ...

```
<a id="myLink" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be outside of the string in order to concatinate your URL.

In this case your string is created using a double quotation mark however you're trying to break out of the string by using a single quotation mark.

I'm assuming here that html is a Javascript variable, which it might not be:

```
var href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + url + ">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.ready(function(){
  var url = "yahoo.com" ; 
   $("#linkid").setAttribute("href",url) ;
}) ;
```

When the browser loads all the elements,  `document.ready` executes the method to set the href attribute of your anchor tag.

So you have an anchor tag like so:

```
<a id="linkid"/>
```

`$("#linkid")` gets the anchor tag element, while setAttribute("href", url) will set the link to your href attribute. 
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: It would be better if you explained why your snippet of code answers the question. Posting just a chunk of code is not that helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok I will. Done, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can just add a javascript variable inside an href like that. Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + url">Foo</a>
```